# WHERE LIKE CONCAT not returning values

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: `companies` and `countries` and I'd like to retrieve the countries by looking at `list_of_countries` field within `companies` table.

```
SELECT id, name
FROM countries
WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('%', (SELECT list_of_countries FROM companies WHERE id = 1), '%')
```

This returns me zero results, and should return two values [**according to this SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/58b62/2).

Comment: `SELECT list_of_countries FROM companies WHERE id = 1` returns `USA, Portugal`. You don't have that combination in `countries`.

Comment: Well, yeah. I was hoping I could select the countries individually by searching for "USA, Portugal".

Comment: You need a normalised database design to take benefit of relational database features. If you store complex data structures in a single cell you lose that possibility. For that, you could just be using TXT files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved** by using INSTR function.

```
SELECT id, name
FROM countries
WHERE INSTR((SELECT list_of_countries FROM companies WHERE id = 1), name) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `find_in_set`:

```
select id,
    name
from countries c
where exists (
        select 1
        from companies c2
        where id = 1
            and find_in_set(c.name, replace(c2.list_of_countries, ', ', ',')) > 0
        )
```

#### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/58b62/18)

Also, you should really consider fixing the table structure.

Answer (score 0):

You should perform the inverse

```
SELECT id, name
FROM countries
WHERE (SELECT list_of_countries FROM companies WHERE id = 1) LIKE CONCAT('%', name, '%')
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/58b62/11

Answer (score 0):

If you can reformat your `list_of_countries`and remove extra spaces.

You can use this kind of query with `FIND_IN_SET` function

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad5ffd/2

```
SELECT c.id, c.name
FROM companies  comp
LEFT JOIN countries c
ON FIND_IN_SET(c.name, comp.list_of_countries)
WHERE comp.id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `find_in_set` in this case. Here my example:

```
select *
from companies t1
left join countries t2 on find_in_set(t2.name, t1.list_of_countries) > 0
```

And here [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/58b62/16).